# How to rename rule in Kie File System

Tags: java, drools

I am creating `kieFileSystem` from `InputStream`, what I need is to create a method which can rename my rules inside the `StatelessKieSession`

Comment: What is the use case that you want to rename the rule file?

Comment: It is just task at work, till Drools 6.0.1 Rule class had lots of methods  such as renameRule...., now there is only some getters.

Comment: Can you example what exactly you want to do? Do you want to rename a `drl file` because you want some changes in the file?